# How to call a user defined function from an if statement

Tags: python

I am just learning Python and it is my first attempt at learning a programming language. I have learned enough to write most a program (very very simple pygLatin translator (I could not think of anything dumber then this to start & challenge myself with hehe)) but I am having a problem calling a function from an if statement.

Here is what I have:

```
def input_state():

    sentence = input("enter a word to be translated: ")
    list = sentence.split()
    for i in list:
        trans_one_word(i)
        new_list.append(another_word)
    s = " "
    print (s.join( new_list ))


input_state()


another = input("Would you like to enter another sentence to be translated? \n Y/N")

if (another == y) or (another == Y):
    input_state()
else:
    input = ("Press any key to exit")
```

I want y or Y to call the input_state() function to be able to enter another sentence and any other key to exit. I prompts the question:

```
another = input("Would you like to enter another sentence to be translated? \n Y/N")
```

but regardless of what key is hit, it still ends the program rather then restarting it.

Comment: `y` and `Y` are not strings but variables. How does that can even work?

Comment: `y` and `Y` are variables. Did you mean to use `'y'` and `'Y'` (string literals) perhaps? You could simplify this to `if another in {'y', 'Y'}:` or simpler still, to `if another.lower() == 'y':`.

Comment: `input = ("Press any key to exit")`: that is wrong too :)

Comment: what is wrong with input = ("Press any key to exit")

Comment: You're comparing another to identifiers that do not exist. You've not assigned a value to the variable y or Y. You should enclose these in quotes if you want your program to run without throwing a NameError here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you must be tired :) let me rephrase it: `input` _equals_ `("press any key")`. See the problem ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: heh, yeah, I did miss that.

Comment: hehe yea, I just noticed that myself. It is ok tho, I erased that input statement. All in all, I think I did a pretty damn good job since I am a beginner and only had to ask for help on that one "if" statement. I am proud of myself and thankful for the quick responses you all have given me.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function in Python, the program will execute the function, then resume its progress where the function was called. In your case, calling `input_state()` does not "loop", it just calls it once, and then goes to the next line, which is the end of the program. You want to have use a `while` loop that checks everytime if it should run. Also, use `if another.lower() == 'y'` instead of `if (another == y) or (another == Y)`.

Comment: He could also do `if another in ('y', 'Y'):` which I prefer because it's concise and doesn't involve calling another function. Technically he could even write something like `if another in 'yY':` but that would not be idiomatic python. Regardless, membership tests in tuples don't have the overhead of calling another function and IMO are more readable.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think performance matters too much here. I tend to that method as well.

Comment: Sure, performance here is not a concern and pythonic thinking dictates that we should care about performance only if the better performing solution is clear and readable, or if performance is a concern or project constraint. Still,  I think it's better for new programmers to have some basic understanding of computer architecture in the sense that they should understand what happens in memory when a program is executed, when a function is called, when an object is instantiated, etc. This doesn't require a degree in CS and causes the programmer to subconsciously consider such things.

Comment: I just posted a snippet of what the program was Raphaël Gomès. I understood that from what I posted it did not look as tho it would do much, but I have now posted the whole of the program on here and you can see that it does indeed do more then it appears. But I do thank you for the constructive criticisim.